# how to configure xcode project for building and distributing a static universal library

Tags: xcode

I have some proprietary C code that I would like to distribute to third parties as a static universal library for ios. How do I properly configure my xcode project to build a universal binary (fat) containing all the suitable architectures?

Is it possible to configure xcode to build my library with all architectures say arm6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 included? I am guessing that these architectures would be needed to build for all possible ios simulator and all possible iphone devices.

I will probably endup writing a shell script including xcodebuild and lipo commands but I would like to minimize the complexity of such a script and get my xcode project configured properly to handle most of the job.

So I would like to know the best practices to build and deliver a library using xcode 5.
Btw shall I use xcode's project templates such as ios library or os framework? I am just using a standard app template where I replaced the files with my code.

Thanks,

baba

Answer (score 0):

You start by creating a new static library target for your project. You can specify which architectures to build. To make sure you build all architectures into your library, make sure `Build Active Architecture Only` is set to `No`. Now once you build this target, the library will be created in the derived data folder. You can change the build location to a more convenient location by selecting File -> Project Settings... and selecting a different folder.